# PowerGUI PS1 to EXE Product Information

Tags: powershell, powergui

I am using  PowerGUI to compile exe. It's working great.
But I wanted to add detail about the exe file, like product version, description, filerversion and etc.

Is there way to do that? I know NSIS script can detail to exe, but how can PowerGUI do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry MoA,

No can do in PowerGUI.